# Android ViewPager Fragments not destroyed when leaving the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have Fragments which are managed inside a ViewPager and works pretty well. It uses FragmentStatePagerAdapter to manage the fragments and all of them are from the same type.

This ViewPager is working inside of a **parent fragment**. 
However, when the user clicks the back button to leave the parent fragment, the fragments that inside the ViewPager won't go into Pause->Destroy->onDetach etc'

They seems to stay in their onResume state even when they no longer visible, although the parent fragment, which created the PagerAdapter has been destroyed and detached properly.

Imagine that when the user seems to be in another screen already, then when he clicks the home button I can see that the Fragments that was in ViewPager (which are no longer visible) go into their Pause state, and when the user navigate back to the app, I can see that the Fragments that was in the ViewPager resumed again while they not visible.

Is there any explanation for such behaviour?

Here portion of my code which initialise the PagerAdapter in the parent fragment:

```
private fun configureScreen() {
    tabs_view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = TabsPagerAdapter.NUM_PAGES - 1

    fragmentManager?.let {
        tabsPagerAdapter = TabsPagerAdapter(it)
        tabs_view_pager.adapter = tabsPagerAdapter
    }
}
```

And here a portion of the PagerAdapter code:

```
class TabsPagerAdapter(fm : FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    companion object {
        const val NUM_PAGES = 3
        private var pagesTitle = arrayOf("" , "", "")
    }


    override fun getItem(item: Int): Fragment {
        return ChildFragment.newInstance()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return NUM_PAGES
    }

    fun updateChildFragments(someData: FragmentData?) {
            //process new data
            notifyDataSetChanged()
       }
    }

    override fun getItemPosition(fragment: Any): Int {
        (fragment as ChildFragment).refresh()
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a viewPager with fragments inside another fragment you should call `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Thanks! Just what i missed!!